# Shell programming, pipe outputfil

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

a newbie to shell programming here.

I have this codes so far:

```
prog inputfile outputfile1

sort -rn outputfile1 | cut -f1-2 > outputfile2
```

My question is there a way to pipe the outputfile directly from the first command to the second to get outputfile2, i.e. skipping the need to create an outputfile1? prog is a custom program that takes inputfile and outpufile names as parameters.

The closest thing I have found is substitution in shell, e.g.

```
sort <(ls dir)
```

But it's not really helpful in this case as I want to pipe the outputfile only and not the stdout. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is why `prog`s should *never* require that their input and output files are provided as filenames. Most Unix utilities write to standard output unless you explicitly specify an output filename with an option (usually `-o`), they read from standard input unless argument filenames are given, and they support `-` as an argument to denote standard input or output.

Comment: nah, @reinierpost, this is why bash provides mechanism for dealing with it :) You can't expect all progs behave uniformly in any way ;-)

Comment: @reinierpost Well it's a bit more complicated to ask the author to fix it rather than myself finding a workaround to it. But thanks for your comment, I'll keep that in mind when writing my own programs in the future. :)

Comment: Well, `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout` aren't provided by bash, but by the POSIX(-like) environment.  I suppose they';re present on most machine that run Unix shells these days - I mostly use Linux and Cygwin, which have them.

Comment: `/dev/fd/*` are Linux-only, plus the few OSes that can emulate a Linux procfs (fbsd, openbsd, probably others). Additionally, Bash handles them internally for a few constructs (redirects, and the `[[` command), which can be used on any OS. Several other GNU programs such as `sed` also have special exceptions for files named `/dev/std{in,out,err}` under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right — the opposite:

```
prog inputfile >(sort -rn | cut -f1-2 >outputfile)
```

depending on the prog you may use

```
prog inputfile /dev/stdout | sort -rn | cut -f1-2 >outputfile
```

or even

```
prog inputfile - | sort -rn | cut -f1-2 >outputfile
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! The first 2 methods worked for me, but not the third. By the way, what is method/workaround called? I'd like to read up more about it. :)

Comment: Ask `prog`'s author to fix it.

Comment: I have no idea if it has a name. In the first case you pass the input of subshell as a filename, in the second case you pass stdout (the problem may arise if your program outputs something you don't really need in its stdout) the third one is a common way to specify stdout for output file, but it requires program to recognize this notation.

Comment: It is called *process substitution*, not to be confused with *command substitution* which uses $( ) or back-ticks.  It uses a named pipe, which is an alternative mechanism if your shell does not support this feature (like ksh88).

Comment: Yeah, the first one. Does the second one (referring to /dev/stdout or /dev/fd/1) have name? Does it even need one? :)